# C# - Prevention of automatic timezone conversion of datetime values while getting data from database through WCF

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# client server application with the server in a different geographical region than the client ie. across time zones. The application makes use of WCF as the middle tier between the UI and Server.
Our requirement is to fetch data from the database and display it in the UI.
The problem is that the datetime columns values (part of the DataTables loaded with data from the database) are automatically getting converted to the local date,time at the client region.

Is there any setting in WCF which prevents automatic timezone conversion of datetime values
that are a part of a dataset?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Sujay

Comment: Do you have to use `DateTime`? Have you tried using `DateTimeOffset`?

Answer (score 1):

Use UTC time across application running on different time zone. Convert them back to local time when needed.